# What is required for an Admin managed Chrome Extension to be capable of accepting a configuration JSON uploaded into the console?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-admin-sdk

We need the same ability (as Google Sign Builder) to consume a configuration file associated with our custom extension -- but I read that the extension needs to be capable of doing so first, before the Admin Console UI provides an option to upload.

See: [Chrome Policies](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6177447#policies) and click its "Install custom policies for an app" section for the console's UI example I reference above.

I see mentions here of a **managed_schema** entry in the extension's manifest.json -- I cannot find any references to this attribute nor any working example of such a thing. Can someone provide one here please?

Our Google Admin for Business support re-directed me here to ask this developer community.

Feel free to review this extension's [source code](https://github.com/theflyingape/bidmc-helper)

Comment: Re schema - see [this article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage).

Comment: [Configuring Apps and Extensions by Policy](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions) also hints that Policies for Chrome OS must be configured via the admin console at https://admin.google.com.  And that the policy for the extension can be uploaded in a txt file after the extension has been selected to be configured. **Note that this option only appears for extensions that support policy configuration.**

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks for the link -- I'll digest it and see if that helps!